# displayMessage instead of showMessageDialog

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm creating my first program in java (in Netbeans), it is basically a SystemTray Icon with a popup menu with different functions for every item. In the following Item I want to use "displayMessage" instead of "showMessageDialog" after that the image was saved. I've tried with `trayIcon.displayMessage("Message", "message", TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);` but it doesn't work and I don't know why, do you have any idea?

```
      item5.addActionListener(new ActionListener () {
        @Override

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            BufferedImage image = null;

            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SupTray.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            try {
                image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
            } catch (AWTException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SupTray.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HH.mm.ss");
                Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+"\\Desktop\\"+formatter.format(now.getTime())+".png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SupTray.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "L'immagine è stata salvata nel desktop.", "Cattura schermata", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if it makes any difference in this case, but in general you should specify the component the dialog should be displayed on (null in JOptionPane.showMessageDialog).
I had some unnecessary issues not doing this some time ago.